# Stopwatch getting faster every click of 'Start' button

Tags: python, timer, stopwatch

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
app = QApplication([])
window = uic.loadUi("exercise3.ui")

timer = QTimer()


def start():
    timer.start(10)
    timer.timeout.connect(updateDisplay)


time = 0
def updateDisplay():
    global time
    time += 1
    text = str(time/100)
    window.timeDisplay.setText(text)


def stop():
    timer.stop()


window.startButton.clicked.connect(start)
window.stopButton.clicked.connect(stop)

window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Hi, super beginner here, not sure why, but every time I press the start button in the GUI, the stopwatch seems to get faster and faster, almost as if the interval is changing. Not quite sure what's going on, would appreciate if someone could help, thank you!

Comment: the code seems to be correct, have you actually checked with a stopwatch / any alternative method?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar I've tested it using the window that comes up when I execute the code, and each time the start button is pressed, the stopwatch gets noticeably faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved it! The 'timeout.connect()' call should be outside of the start() slot. Somehow, when it was in the start() slot, it seems like the signal was connected multiple times to the same slot, resulting in the slot being called multiples times too, making it accelerate every time it was called.